# The distribution of one variable, which is a function of another, random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Suppose I have the following equation:

```
a = -(Log[(1 - b)/b]/Log[10])
```

which is visualized as

[image]

Suppose further that $b$ is drawn from a uniform distribution with minimum $L$ and maximum $H$, where $0<L<H<1$. For example $L = 0.6$ and $H = 0.8$.

How can I use Mathematica to find the associated distribution of $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html):

```
a = -(Log[(1 - b)/b]/Log[10]);
l = .6; h = .8;
td = TransformedDistribution[a, Distributed[b, UniformDistribution[{l, h}]]];

PDF[td, x] // TeXForm
```

> $\small\begin{cases}
>  \frac{5.75646 e^{2.30259 x}}{0.5\, +1. e^{2.30259 x}+0.5 e^{4.60517 x}} & 0.176091<x<0.60206\land 1. e^{2.30259 x}\geq 1.5\land e^{-2.30259 x}\geq 0.25 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

```
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[td, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[pdF]
pdF[l_, h_] := PDF @ TransformedDistribution[-(Log[(1 - b)/b]/Log[10]), 
        Distributed[b, UniformDistribution[{l, h}]]];

Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[pdF[l, h][x]], {x, -1, 1}, 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"{l, h} =", {l, h}}], 16], PlotRange -> {0, 2}],
 {{l, .2}, 0, 1}, {{h, .6}, l, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it...  Yep:  again!  If we were gunslingers in the wild west, you would (it seems) always beat me by just a fraction of a second!  (No wonder your reputation is 157k!)

Comment: @David, again?:)

Comment: What does the y-axis show here? I was expecting probabilties.

Comment: @user120911, y-axis show Probability Density Function (PDF), If you want to show  Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)  you can replace `PDF` in the code with `CDF`.